# Postgres issues on mac. Want to clean up and do a fresh install

Tags: mac, uninstall, postgresql

Am a noob to Mac OS and having trouble with Postgres on it. Initially installed Postgres 11 via the EnterpriseDB installer. Due to an issue with the system user name on mac having the '.' character, I created another mac user and re-installed Postgres via Homebrew, this time v9.6 since I came to know that was the version used in prod. Im not able to login to postgres. Have already tried a lot of advice on the internet and no luck. Now as a last resort I want to nuke the installs and start afresh.
Im seeing

> LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address already in use
>   2019-08-06 12:14:48.429 IST [12386] HINT:  Is another postmaster
>   already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.

and ps auxwww | grep postgres

```
postgres           513   0.0  0.0  4379700   2132   ??  S     6:39PM   0:00.29 /usr/libexec/trustd --agent
postgres           512   0.0  0.0  4379248   1152   ??  S     6:39PM   0:00.04 /usr/libexec/lsd
postgres           511   0.0  0.0  4333792    488   ??  S     6:39PM   0:00.03 /usr/sbin/cfprefsd agent
postgres           201   0.0  0.0  4344296    540   ??  Ss    6:38PM   0:00.95 postgres: stats collector process    
postgres           200   0.0  0.0  4489360   1648   ??  Ss    6:38PM   0:00.27 postgres: autovacuum launcher process    
postgres           199   0.0  0.0  4489296    352   ??  Ss    6:38PM   0:00.26 postgres: wal writer process    
postgres           198   0.0  0.0  4489296    376   ??  Ss    6:38PM   0:00.30 postgres: writer process    
postgres           197   0.0  0.0  4489296    404   ??  Ss    6:38PM   0:00.01 postgres: checkpointer process    
postgres           193   0.0  0.0  4344296    360   ??  Ss    6:38PM   0:00.01 postgres: logger process    
postgres            88   0.0  0.0  4489576   1380   ??  Ss    6:38PM   0:00.34 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
```

What are the steps that need to be done on MacOS to ensure that both the installs are wiped away completely?

**UPDATE**
Found out a way to remove the 9.x installed via Homebrew by running

```
sudo /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh
```

Now,

$ ps aux | grep postgres

```
postgres           513   0.0  0.0  4379700   2880   ??  S     6:39PM   0:00.35 /usr/libexec/trustd --agent
postgres           512   0.0  0.0  4379304   3708   ??  S     6:39PM   0:00.07 /usr/libexec/lsd
postgres           511   0.0  0.0  4333792    916   ??  S     6:39PM   0:00.04 /usr/sbin/cfprefsd agent
postgres         13351   0.0  0.0  4317164   2776   ??  S     2:31PM   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/distnoted agent
```

Not able to remove these processes. Get a

> Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

After getting rid of the 9.6, re-installed 11.4 via homebrew. But still was not able to connect. There were some helpful posts on the internet which prompted a run of initdb. Initdb requires an arg PGDATA. Set PGDATA as an environment variable

export PGDATA=your_location

Then run initdb. 
That fixed my connection issue to postgres finally.